# lucene index downgrading from 4.8 to 4.6

Tags: java, lucene

Is there a way to downgrade an index in lucene from 4.8 to 4.6?

I opened an 4.6 index with luke 4.8 and did some changes not noticing it updated the segments.

I can't work on lucene 4.8 as it needs java 7 and I am stuck with a java 6 server ( a project 
requirement)

Comment: Are you sure it made incompaible changes? The index "knows" its Lucene version and higher versions can always deal with lower ones.

Comment: The case now is that I have two indexes 4.6 and one 4.8 so I updated lucene to 4.8 in order to deal with the later one among the rest but this can't work as I said. Keeping lucene on 4.6 threw an exception when dealing with a 4.8 index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that you can do. Indices are only backward compatible, not forward compatible.